# How do I test a saga with params

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga

Learning how to test a saga (using Jest) for the first time. My saga requires an object passing to it containing a `userId` but I'm getting this error which is obviously highlighting a difference in the arguments:

```
Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": [], "context": null, "fn": [Function getClassrooms]}}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": ["1"], "context": null, "fn": [Function getClassrooms]}}
```

I have:

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { theSaga } from './saga.js';
import { apiCall } from './api';

it('should do something', () => {
  const data = {
    payload: {
      userId: '1'
    }
  };

  const generator = theSaga(data);

  expect(generator.next().value)
    .toEqual(call(apiCall));

});
```

Not sure how I would get the two to match? I've tried changing the line to:

```
.toEqual(call(apiCall('1'));
```

but this gives errors about the function not being a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is a saga function which returns an action to be executed by the saga middleware. `call` expects the arguments to the function to be appended to it's  arguments, so `call(apiCall,1)`. The nice thing about this is that the generator can be tested by simply walking each step and check if the expected action is generated. `expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(apiCall,1))`

That said; I don't see much use in testing a generator this way. You want to test *behaviour* instead of *how* the generator is implemented. You put something in and expect something out (under different circumstances). Testing something like `expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(apiCall,1))` is like saying: I actually programmed what I've programmed, the test confirms that.